# Error initialize AZSCloudStorageAccount Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, azure-blob-storage

I tried link to my account with this code

```
let storageAccount : AZSCloudStorageAccount;

              try! storageAccount = AZSCloudStorageAccount(fromConnectionString: config.getAzureConnection())

            let blobClient = storageAccount.getBlobClient()
             var container : AZSCloudBlobContainer = (blobClient?.containerReference(fromName: config.getContainer()))!
```

the "config.getAzureConnection()" contains the right path because i used the same for android app.

In this line `try! storageAccount = AZSCloudStorageAccount(fromConnectionString: config.getAzureConnection())` the app crash without error, only (lldb) .

Can someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your error look like this?

`fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=com.Microsoft.AzureStorage.ErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)": file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-802.0.53/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 182
(lldb)`

Code=1 is AZSEInvalidArgument, which means that your connection string is invalid. I am a bit confused why you said "the right path", since fromConnectionString takes the string directly, not the path to a file. To see an example of what a correct connection string looks like, please refer to the [Getting Started Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-ios-how-to-use-blob-storage). Basically it looks like this:

`"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=your_account_name_here;AccountKey=your_account_key_here"`

We will document the error codes properly very soon. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

> the app crash without error, only (lldb) .

I am sorry for that SWIFT blob client haven't provide error-handling code whatsoever currently. I will provide some clues to track your issue based on your code.

1. Before building the storage code, make one change in the project.  Go to 'Azure Storage Client Library' -> Build Settings, search for the "Defines Module" setting, and change it to 'YES'.
2. Please check whether the issue is caused by bad network connection.
3. You could get error code of this issue by putting your code in a do-catch code block.

```
do {
    //put your code here
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error code = %ld, error domain = %@, error userinfo = %@", error.code, error.domain, error.userInfo);
}
```

4. The SWIFT blob sample has been tested and work well targeting iOS 9.0 and using XCode 7. If you have a different setup, the sample may not run properly. I suggest you use [Blob Storage REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-rest-api) as a workaround.